# Confused about $O_X$ ideals and closed subschemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I am trying to understand a passage in Mumford's Red Book (Section II. 5, page 146 in the old version). Let $X$ be a scheme,  $Q$ is a subsheaf of $O_X$ such that for all $U$, $Q(U)$ is an ideal in $O_X(U)$, (I assume he means open $U$ here) and we call such an object an $O_X$- ideal.

The part I am trying to understand is the following: We claim that $Q$ determines the closed subschemes up to canonical isomorphisms. For first of all, $Y = \{ x \in X : Q_x \neq O_X \}$, the sequence 
$$
0 \to Q_x \to O_{x,X} \to O_{x, Y} \to 0
$$
is exact, and secondly $O_Y$ extended by zero is canonically isomorphic to the cokernel of $Q \to O_X$. Thus a closed subscheme is really just an $O_X$-ideal.

I am struggling to see how this explains $Q$ determines closed subschemes. 
I have been trying to understand parts of this so I have asked couple related question, but it seems that I am getting more confused...  I would greatly appreciate clarification about this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a scheme, and let $\mathcal{I}$ be a quasi-coherent sheaf of ideals on $X$. Let $Z$ be the support of the quotient $\mathcal{O}_X / \mathcal{I}$, that is
$$ Z=\{x \in X \ | \ (\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I})_x \neq 0 \}.$$
The set $(Z,\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I})$ is a sub-ringed space of $X$. Let $U\subset X$ be a open subset such that $(U,\mathcal{O}_X|_U)\simeq (Spec A,\widetilde{A})$ is affine. Hence $\mathcal{I}|_U$ has the form $\widetilde{I}$, that is it is associated to an ideal $I$ of $A$. Then $(Z\cap U,\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}|_U) \simeq (Spec (A/I), \widetilde{A/I})$.

Note that the inclusion map $i : (Z,\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}) \to (X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is a closed immersion, as the map $\mathcal{O}_X \to i_*(\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I})$ is surjective (on a point $p\in Spec(A)$ it is given by $A_p \to (A/I)_p$).

Comment: How do I know it is quasi-coherent? There seems to be no mention of this in the text...

Comment: @JohnnyT. You can find a complete proof of this on the Bosch's book of algebraic geometry.

Comment: @JohnnyT. The structure sheaf of a closed subscheme is quasi-coherent, so you must start with a quasi-coherent sheaf of ideal $\mathcal{Q}$.

Comment: I see, thank you. What is meant by $\mathfrak{O}_X/\mathfrak{I}$? (Is this the sheafification of the presheaf defined by $\mathfrak{O}_X(V)/\mathfrak{I}(V)$ for all open $V$?) And could you possibly elaborate on how $(Z\cap U,\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}|_U) \simeq (Spec (A/I), A/I)$?

Comment: Yeah, $\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}$ is the sheafification of the presheaf given by the quotient. For your other remark, note that $Z\cap U$ is the subset of $Spec(A)$ of prime ideal $p$ for which $(A/I)_p$ is zero, that is the $p$ for which $I\subset p$. But this is exactly $Spec (A/I)$.